# Создание большого количества элементов динамически

Tags: c#, winforms

Создаю много элементов `flowLayoutPanelN` в `Panel`, и в`flowLayoutPanelN` добавляю `Label`.  Их количество зависит от количества записей в БД. Все работает, но не совсем так как хотелось бы...
Происходит зависание или же пролистывается вверх пока не появятся все элементы. Как можно от этого избавиться.

Вот код

```
flowLayout = new FlowLayoutPanel[data.Count];
name_oneOils = new Label[data.Count];
check = new CheckBox[data.Count];
for (int i = data.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    flowLayout[i] = new FlowLayoutPanel
    {
        AutoSize = true,
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
        Dock = DockStyle.Top,
        FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight
    };
    panel.Controls.Add(flowLayout[i]);
    name_oneOils[i] = new Label
    {
        Anchor = AnchorStyles.None,
        AutoSize = true,
        Font = new Font("Malgun Gothic", 10.8F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0))),
        Name = $"name_oneOils{i}",
        Text = data[i][0],
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    };
    name_oneOils[i].Click += new EventHandler(name_oneOils_Click);
    flowLayout[i].Controls.Add(name_oneOils[i]);
    check[i] = new CheckBox
    {
        Name = $"check{i}",
        Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(data[i][2])
    };
    flowLayout[i].Controls.Add(check[i]);
}
```

https://disk.yandex.ru/i/f9x7xvtF18Y-ng записал как работает приложение

На случай если ссылка будет не активна:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте в начале кода вставить `panel.SuspendLayout()`, а в конце `panel.ResumeLayout()`. И скажите, что получилось.

Comment: @aepot, получилось, Благодарю!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

- перенести добавление в старшую панель в конец цикла
- добавить SuspendLayout
- добавить буферизацию
- создать шрифт 1 раз

```
Font font = new Font("Malgun Gothic", 10.8F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, byte.MinValue);
panel.DoubleBuffered = true; // это надо сделать 1 раз при создании этой панели
panel.SuspendLayout();
for (int i = data.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    flowLayout[i] = new FlowLayoutPanel
    {
        AutoSize = true,
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
        Dock = DockStyle.Top,
        FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight
    };
    name_oneOils[i] = new Label
    {
        Anchor = AnchorStyles.None,
        AutoSize = true,
        Font = font,
        Name = $"name_oneOils{i}",
        Text = data[i][0],
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    };
    name_oneOils[i].Click += new EventHandler(name_oneOils_Click);
    flowLayout[i].Controls.Add(name_oneOils[i]);
    check[i] = new CheckBox
    {
        Name = $"check{i}",
        Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(data[i][2])
    };
    flowLayout[i].Controls.Add(check[i]);
    panel.Controls.Add(flowLayout[i]);
}
panel.ResumeLayout();
```