# Скрыть окно без Hide и Close

Tags: c#, winforms

Моя программа показывает окно поверх других окон при определённым событиях. 
Я нашёл способ - через this.Visible, но этот способ не работает если на форме есть хоть какой-нибудь объект, как понимаете, мне очень важно иметь на форме объекты.
Единственный способ, который я нашёл - Graphics, я могу рисовать на этой форме и Visible будет работать. Но через Graphics будет очень-очень-очень сложно отрисовать свои объекты, а потом перехватывать ивенты мышки и клавиатуры чтобы эмитировать ивенты Click и.т.д. 
Как возможно очень быстро скрывать и открывать окно? (Hide и Show не подходит из-за медленной работы)

Так же как вариант решения моей проблемы - удалить окно из Alt Tab, тогда юзер не как не может его увидеть и проблема будет решена

Comment: Запомнить текущие координаты и переместить окно за пределы монитора `this.Location = new Point(-20000, -20000);`, но при этом фокус останется на окне, и по Alt+Tab его будет видно. Можно конечно фокус следом перебросить на другое окно. Я только не понимаю, как это `Hide` медленно работает? Почему он у меня окно скрывает мгновенно, а у вас - нет? Быть может вы что-то делаете не так? Например после вызова Hide продолжаете синхронно выполнять код, чего делать не нужно, покажите код, где у вас Hide тормозит..

Comment: 1) У меня слабый пк, из-за чего глаз сильно замечает отдельную прогрузку каждого элемента. При использовании поля Visible - всё быстро.
2) Перемещение фокуса легко исправляется с помощью SetForegroundWindow(Вроде бы правильно назвал функцию WinAPI)

Comment: Если бы вы все сделали правильно, прогрузка была бы не видна, и выполнялась бы быстрее, обратите внимание на этот ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1376796/373567

Comment: SuspendLayout вызывает некоторые побочки, например - начинает показывать скроллбар у панели

Comment: Я всё же попробую Location

Comment: Жаль что SuspendLayout не работает с Graphics панели, там нужно отдельно что-то с буфером делать чтобы не было мерцаний панели

Comment: Есть еще другие способы вообще приморозить отрисовку полностью, но я не помню, где оно у меня закопано. Если найду - покажу.

Comment: @aepot, да, сработало, до сих пор не нашёл проблем.

Comment: Ок, но я все же лучше предложу разобраться с тормозами, чем втыкать такого рода костыль. Пользы больше будет. Наверняка у вас код просто медленный на отрисовке висит. Или Show/Hide вызываете вместе с другим тяжелым кодом. К слову, винформы у меня вполне быстро работали и на компе 15-летней давности. У них есть плюс, они очень легковесные. Так что ставлю рубль, что вопрос решаемый без читерства.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133783/discussion-between-yotic-and-aepot).